# Why does numpy make a type casting for np.float16(3.0) + 0 and np.float32(3.0) + 0?

Tags: python, numpy, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

Can you explain why such type casting is performed?

```
In [49]: type(np.float16(3.0) + 0)
Out[49]: numpy.float64

In [50]: type(np.float32(3.0) + 0)
Out[50]: numpy.float64
```

Although the following works as expected

```
In [52]: type(np.float16(3.0) + np.float16(0))
Out[52]: numpy.float16

In [53]: type(np.float32(3.0) + np.float32(0))
Out[53]: numpy.float32
```

The question is when we do `np.float16(3.0) + 0` and `np.float16(3.0) + 0` why is everything upcast to `numpy.float64`, instead of to `numpy.float16` and `numpy.float32` respectively?

Comment: Probably because the C code that underlies it all works that way.

Comment: Specify the float dtype for the 0 as well, `np.float16(10)+np.float16(0)`.  `0` is a Python int, Python's float is equivalent to `float64` (or possibly 32 on smaller machines).  Python does not have an equivalent to `float16`.   Also look at `np.array(0, float)`.